# Investing in German stocks as a USA citizen

Tags: germany, adr

I currently invest in a German company through an ADR, but have been informed that the ADR is being shutdown.  I am thinking about investing directly on the German stock market.

What fees, taxes, etc... should I be expecting?  I consider myself a long term investor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy foreign stock by opening an account with a broker that has access to foreign markets, either in the US or abroad.  There are restrictions on US persons buying stock options on exchanges not registered with the SEC (all of them) but otherwise there are not restrictions.

You will have to pay tax on your dividends which
may be qualified or non qualified.  If your broker is in the US they should tell you and provide you with the necessary documentation for you to complete your tax return.

The main complexity you may face is that you have to buy the stock in local currency, so may have to convert to local currency to buy the stock and calculate the exchange rate at the time any dividend is paid in order to correctly report dividend income for tax purposes.  If you buy and sell the stock you will need to calculate the purchase price and sale price in USD for capital gains tax purposes.  These are not difficult things to do but can add an additional step when calculating your taxes.